# MySQL Sum and Subtract according to the records?

Tags: mysql, row, sum, addition

I have a record in mysql which contains something like this:

```
+15,+23,-21,+23,-3
```

All I want to do is that in a SQL query these values get added and subtracted according to their signs.

I know of `SUM()`, but what about the subtraction? Basically, I need something that can be executed in one query, like the following example:

```
SELECT SUM(result) AS 'total' FROM mytable  WHERE year='2011' AND month='10';
```

Comment: it didn't worked back... but i tried it with different syntax this time and it worked :/

Comment: Note that `year` and `month` are reserved words and need to be quotes in backticks ` in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will work correctly. Tested on

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into test values(null, 5), (null, -1), (null,4);
select sum(p) from test;
```

Result is 8.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a comma separated field in your database.

That's a huge NONO, (My)SQL is not very well equipped to deal with this.
If you have no more than 5 values in every row you can do something like:

**Awkward code warning**

```
$month = mysql_real_escape_string($data['month']);
$year = mysql_real_escape_string($data['year']);
$sql = "SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',1),0) 
  + IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',2),0)
  + IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',3),0)
  + IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',4),0)  
  + IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',5),0) as total_result
FROM mytable
WHERE `year` = '$year' AND `month` = '$month' ";
```

I'm not 100% sure MySQL will be happy with the '+' signs, if not you'll need to filter them out by doing  `REPLACE(IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(result,',',2),0),'+','')`

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

**Refactoring you database**
I recommend that you kick the CSV habit and normalize your database.

Put the values into different rows (one value per row) and merge the `month` and `year` columns into one, and add a `auto_increment integer primary key` column named `id`

Your table will look something like:

```
id    result    mydate
1     15       2011-01-01
2     13       2011-01-01
3     -15      2011-01-01
...
4875  -23      2011-08-28
```

Now you can add the sum of results in a particular month by doing:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(result) as totalresult 
FROM mytable
WHERE mydate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' ";
```

Using the `between ... and` construct instead of the functions `YEAR(mydate) and MONTH(mydate)` will allow MySQL to use an index to select the values.
You you wrap a column in a function MySQL cannot use an index slowing things down a lot.